# Modify edit menu on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to add another menu element to the edit menu that appears when clicking on a UITextField, for instance. For example the one in the following image:

[image: Edit menu]

I have been investigating how to do it but no luck. So far I have seen mostly how to create a completely new menu, or remove some actions from the current one. 
Is it possible to just add another menu item to the menu in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this. Even though the naming is actually confusing, the place where to set additional menu items is `UIMenuController.shared.menuItems`. From the name I thought it would just change override the default menu items, but I was wrong.

Another important part of the puzzle is to remember to override `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)` to return true in the cases in which the button should be visible